# Android Radio Button doesn't get checked sometimes

Tags: android, multithreading, radio-button, radio-group

I have 4 `RadioButton`s in a `RadioGroup`. The `RadioButton`s have the same instance of `OnCheckedChangedListener` set. When any of the `RadioButton` is selected a dialog is popped up after 800ms using a handler. The problem is, sometimes any of the `RadioButton`s remains unchecked even after the checked state is changed, but the dialog pops up. I suspect this to be a bug. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of calling `RadioButton.setChecked()` for every individual instance I called `RadioGroup.clearChecked()`, this seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: It works fine for me too. Terrible Android's bug. Thanks for share with us!